# Flutter ListTile content overlay Card when apply Slidable

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, slide

I am applying a `Slidable` widget on my `Card` widget to allow user to take do action based on their needs. However, when I slide the card the content in the card overlay the `Card` widget which doesn't look nice from the UI. The following is my sample code and the image attached is the output I currently obtained.

[image: Output]

Sample Code:

```
Card(
  child: Slidable(
    endActionPane: ActionPane(motion: const DrawerMotion(), children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                gradient: customColors.progressBarGradient),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.local_phone_rounded,
                        color: Colors.white)),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.mail_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white)),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.mail_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white)
              ],
            )))
      ]),
  child: ListTile(
      dense: true,
      leading: const AccountIcon(size: 42),
      title: Text('KOO KIAN KEAT'),
      subtitle:
          Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Text('----')
      ])),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the whole `Card` widget with `Slidable` widget to make it slide all together. And I also wrapped `Slidable` with `Container` widget which imitates card styling and will adjust the shape and color when start sliding (look at the end of the card widget when start sliding):

```
// This container follows card decoration and adjusts shape (and backgroud color) when sliding
Container(
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    // imitating card shape
    shape: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.shape ??
        // material 3 default card shape
        const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
        ),
    // using card color (this is default card color)
    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
  ),
  child: Slidable(
    endActionPane: ActionPane(
      motion: const DrawerMotion(),
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.local_phone_rounded,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.mail_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.mail_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    child: const Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      elevation: 0,
      child: ListTile(
        dense: true,
        leading: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, size: 50),
        title: Text('KOO KIAN KEAT'),
        subtitle: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [Text('----')],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```